# Ethereum signature as XML

Tags: signature, message, secp256k1

I am seeking to express an EIP 191 0x45 message signature according to the [XML Signature Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-KeyInfo).

I assume this curve is the correct one: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1

For a signature over `sha256("foo")` signed by `eb3907ecad74a0013c259d5874ae7f22dcbcc95c` (pubkey `049f6bb6a7e3f5b7ee71756a891233d1415658f8712bac740282e083dc9240f5368bdb3b256a5bf40a8f7f9753414cb447ee3f796c5f30f7eb40a7f5018fc7f02e`), are the parameters applied to the structure given below:

1. correct, and
2. contain everything needed to verify the signature from scratch (except the data).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Signature Id="sig-a0f819f9-6813-4f14-a7c8-f33c12f0c846" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">                                           
        <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>                                          
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6931"/>
                <Reference Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties">                                                       
                        <Transforms>                                                                                                           
                                <Transform Algorithm="https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-191#version-0x45-e" />                                
                                <Transform Algorithm="https://csrc.nist.gov/glossary/term/sha_256" />                                          
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="https://csrc.nist.gov/glossary/term/sha_256" />                                               
                        <DigestValue>drLpZxTTtebrHRxQkmVDC5B7RPcrKiKwb81NljcrhWU=</DigestValue>                                                
                </Reference>                                                                                                                   
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>r3d2ftvM30Y4D+1vBq9DyAfeS+3OLtoSmSM0DpV3yX52vFXVhxA6NnBXFn81GuHP1rjepuAoIlfeNZT749h4BwA=</SignatureValue>              
            
        <KeyInfo>
                <KeyName>6zkH7K10oAE8JZ1YdK5/Ity8yVw=</KeyName>                                                                                
                <!-- public key: 049f6bb6a7e3f5b7ee71756a891233d1415658f8712bac740282e083dc9240f5368bdb3b256a5bf40a8f7f9753414cb447ee3f796c5f30f7eb40a7f5018fc7f02e -->
                <ECKeyValue xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmldsig11">                                                                          
                        <PublicKey>BJ9rtqfj9bfucXVqiRIz0UFWWPhxK6x0AoLgg9ySQPU2i9s7JWpb9AqPf5dTQUy0R+4/eWxfMPfrQKf1AY/H8C4=</PublicKey>        
                        <ECParameters>                                                                                                         
                                <FieldID>
                                        <Prime>                                                                                                
                                                <P>/////////////////////////////////////v///C8=</P>                                            
                                        </Prime>
                                </FieldID>
                                <Curve>
                                        <A>AA==</A>
                                        <B>Bw==</B>                                                                                            
                                </Curve>                                                                                                       
                                <Base>BHm+Zn753LusVaBilc6HCwcCm/zbLc4o2VnygVsW+BeYSDradyajxGVdpPv8DhEIqP0XtEimhVQZnEfQj/sQ1Lg=</Base>
                                <Order>/////////////////////rqu3OavSKA7v9JejNA2QUE=</Order>                                                    
                                <CoFactor>1</CoFactor> 
                        </ECParameters>
                </ECKeyValue>
        </KeyInfo>                                                                                                                             
        <Object>
                <SignatureProperties>                                                                                                          
                        <SignatureProperty Id="ts-a0f819f9-6813-4f14-a7c8-f33c12f0c846" Target="sig-a0f819f9-6813-4f14-a7c8-f33c12f0c846">     
                                <timestamp xmlns="https://www.epochconverter.com/">                                                            
                                        <epochSeconds>1686900525</epochSeconds>                                                                
                                </timestamp>                                                                                                   
                        </SignatureProperty>                                                                                                   
                </SignatureProperties>                                                                                                         
        </Object>
</Signature>
```

validated against:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xmldsig-core-20080610/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd
- https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig11-schema.xsd